# Negative Value not printed correctly

Tags: vb.net, printing, printdocument

In my project printing a negative value with format flag right to left. but it print a value like this `"136-"`. What am do wrongly? How to print value like `"-1233".`

Am setting string format like this:

```
Dim mAmtFormat As New StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft)
```

Using format in printdocument like this:

`e.Graphics.DrawString("-123", mTextFont, Brushes.Black, mConsumMeas.xQtyX, mTop, mAmtFormat`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right-to-left format is used for languages that are read from right to left. You want to use alignment to align the text to the right:

```
Dim mAmtFormat As New StringFormat()
mAmtFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far
```